# Spring JPA - Many to one without full foreign object

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I am experimenting with spring and jpa's `ManyToOne` in [this repo](https://github.com/MaxHoefl/springboot-jpademo). The relationship between the entities is that one `Cart` (shopping cart) can have many `Item`s (following [this tutorial](http://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-one-to-many)).

**Cart**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="CART")
public class Cart 
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "cart_id")
    private long id;


    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "cart")
    private Set<Item> items;

    /* rest of class*/
```

**Item**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="ITEMS")
public class Item
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private long id;

    @Column(name="item_name")
    private String itemName;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "cart_id", nullable = false)
    private Cart cart; // needs an entire Cart instance :(

     /* rest of class*/
```

### Question

How can I map the `Item`s to the `Cart` class without making the entire `Cart` object part of the `Item` class.

I want to look the `Item` class to look like this

```
@Entity
@Table(name="ITEMS")
public class Item
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private long id;

    @Column(name="item_name")
    private String itemName;


    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "cart_id", nullable = false)
    private long cartId; // just the ID of Cart, not the entire Cart object
```

This gives the errors

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @OneToOne or @ManyToOne on com.example.demo.Item.cartId references an unknown entity: long
    at org.hibernate.cfg.ToOneFkSecondPass.doSecondPass(ToOneFkSecondPass.java:97) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.12.Final.jar:5.2.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processEndOfQueue(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1752) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.12.Final.jar:5.2.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processFkSecondPassesInOrder(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1696) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.12.Final.jar:5.2.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1583) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.12.Final.jar:5.2.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:278) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.12.Final.jar:5.2.12.Final]
```

which doesn't really surprise me. But I want to be somehow able to instantiate an `Item` without an entire `Cart` instance. Ideally, just the `Cart` ID as a field in `Item` would suffice.

**EDIT**

So if I have to make `Cart` a field in `Item` how to I initialize the db with a `data-h2.sql` script? There is no SQL way to express what a `Cart` is!

Comment: You may also set lazy-fetching on `items` , i.e `@OneToMany(mappedBy = "cart", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)` .

Comment: `@ManyToOne` used to reference an Object not a primitive type, so i think that when you instantiate an Item, you will not instanciate a Cart Object, to secure this issue you might use a Lazy load mechanism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just remove the reference back to the `Cart` completely and make the complete relationship go just in one direction by dropping the `mappedBy="cart"` part from the `@OneToMany` annotation.

If you still want the `cart_id` in the item you can set it using java code on the `Cart`.

Of course, all this begs the question: Why do you want this behavior which is very un-JPA-ish. If you create another question stating your original question/concern it seems likely that there is something to learn about JPA.

Comment: it seems natural to me that the `Item` stores only the foreign key `cart_id` additionally to it's own `id`. That's all what's needed to establish the relationship. Putting the entire `Cart` object into `Item` seems unnecessary to me

Comment: If you prefer handling ids instead of JPA might not the right choice. Also, the phrasing "seems unnecessary" suggest some additional cost for using an object reference. This cost certainly doesn't exist on the developer side. And if you dealing with Items you probably have the Cart loaded anywhere so there should be if at all a minimal cost of having a reference.