# Spring JPA - post resource in many to one relationships

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jpa, spring-data-jpa

This question is closely related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48828269/spring-jpa-many-to-one-without-full-foreign-object/48831607?noredirect=1#comment84671002_48831607) (Solving this one here, will probably also solve the other).

In my [spring mvc app](https://github.com/MaxHoefl/springboot-jpademo) (github) I have two resources: `Cart` and `Item` where a cart can have multiple items.

The `CartController` maps a POST method which adds a random item to a cart with a given ID

```
/* Forgetting about response entity and null checking etc. for now */

    @PostMapping("carts/rdm/{id}")
    public Cart addRandomItem(@PathVariable("id") long id)
    {
        String[] rdmItemNames = {"toothbrush", "shampoo", "body wash"};
        int rnd = new Random().nextInt(rdmItemNames.length);
        String itemName = rdmItemNames[rnd];

        // Add new item to the cart with given id
        Cart cart = dao.getById(id);

        Item item = new Item();
        item.setItemName(itemName);

        // This works but I have to create a new cart object with same id
        Cart sameCart = new Cart();
        sameCart.setId(cart.getId());
        item.setCart(sameCart);

        // This doesn't work, no surprise but I would like to
        // just retrieve the Cart, add the new Item and be done.
        // item.setCart(cart);
        // cart.getItems().add(item);
        return dao.save(cart);
    }
```

After POSTing to `http://localhost:9100/carts/rdm/1`, I get the following `Cart` json

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "items": [
        {
            "id": 0,
            "itemName": "body wash",
            "cart": {
                "id": 1,
                "items": null
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Feels like I am not understanding JPA correctly. This boils down again to why the `Item` object needs to contain the whole `Cart` object. If `Item` only contained the foreign key (the cart id), then I could produce a json like this

```
   {
        "id": 1,
        "items": [
            {
                "id": 0,
                "itemName": "body wash",
                "cart_id": 1
            }
        ]
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JPA is a high level ORM Framework. Which means that the object-references of java are converted to relational references in your Database.

So in your database you will have a foreign key where an item references a car.

JPA converts these relational-relation to object-relations, which means that you will get not only the reference of the car but the car object.

Your Rest-API return the Java-Object which holds Object-References. That is why your item contains a Car-Object.

If you want to return only the car_id you have to map your output to a new object.

Answer (score 0):

I am junior with REST , but  my advice would be :
Create CartServices class . Controller only to transfer data to Services.
Use @transactional annotations. It is hard to read .
I wrote very similar Application : IF you want to check :
https://github.com/justassub/ShopProject/tree/master/RESTserver/src/main/java/lt/it/akademija
Sorry , it was my first application and not everything was in english. BUT IT IS VERY SIMILAR - only Cart - users.

When you wrote :

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "cart")
private Set<Item> items;
```

write method :

```
public void addItem(Item item) {
    this.items.add(item);
    item.setCart(this);
}
```

and then Cart.addItem(item);
And other
OF course you need to create getCart/setCart in your items List